# Socket doesnt work after homestead update

Tags: sockets, laravel, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After creating a socket and use Redis for it, it works fine. But then i started with the queue to run background processes and broadcast them if finished. So i start downloading a "tool" beanconsole and add a domain to my homestead. After i've finished everything, i opened my domain, tested my socket and it was broken. So i start to revert everything and after 30 minutes i figured out that when i change the path from /var/www/ to /var/www/project that my socket didnt received any messages any more.

Someone know how to solve this?